# Pentaho - connect to apache hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have problem with connections to apache hive databases. I get:

[image]

I change:

```
active.hadoop.configuration=hdp31
```

but it doesn't work.
Does anyone have any idea?
In dbeaver I can connect to databases

Answer (score 0):

The error already told you the reason "No suitable driver found for jdbc:hive". Issue might be solved with below steps:-

1. You were missed to keep hive JDBC driver in location "data-integration/lib/"
2. Or You can try with an old hive jdbc driver version 1.2.1 ("jdbc-1.2.1.jar")
3. Or You can use latest hive jdbc driver and use **Connection type =Hadoop Hive 2/3** during connection in PDI.
4. Or If JAR "pentaho-hadoop-shims-common-fragment-V1-x-x-x-x-x.jar" available in location "data-integration\plugins\pentaho-big-data-plugin\hadoop-configurations\hdp30\lib\pmr" then also you can try with "connection type=Hadoop Hive 2/3" in PDI

Please let me know if this work for you.

[image]

Comment: It's getting better, but it still doesn't work. In answer I put what I get